# Updating Freeform Pro to 4.1.7 gives undefined property error

Tags: solspace-freeform

I just performed an update to Freeform Pro going from version 4.1.3 to 4.1.7. After the update all pages where I've embedded a form I'm getting the following PHP Error:

```
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$csrf_name
```

Rolling back to the previous version fixes the issue. Is there something I need to change in how I add composer templates? Below is an example of one I use:

```
{exp:freeform:composer
    form_name="contact_us"
    composer_template_name="default_calvary_forms"
    return="new/contact_us?return=success"
    inline_error_return="new/contact_us"
    inline_errors="yes"
}
```

I'm running this on EE version 2.7.3.